# Ubuntu only allow incoming access from 192.168.0.0/8 or server IP address

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ip

How can I make it that only approved IP addresses have access to my Ubuntu server 12.04 I only just set it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with following commands provided you have `UFW` install:

To allow by a specific IP address use,

```
sudo ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

To allow by a specific subnet we invoke netmask and use,

```
sudo ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/XX
```

To allow by a specific port and an IP address you can use,

```
sudo ufw allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX to AAA port YY
```

Please refer [community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) for advance help.

---

Using [tcpwrappers](http://www.clug.org/presentations/security/tcpwrappers.html),

/etc/hosts.deny is checked before /etc/hosts.allow, so you can go

- hosts.deny

  ALL : ALL

first, we block everything from everyone,

- hosts.allow

  ALL : localhost

  sshd: 192.168.0.2

which means only 192.168.0.2 on your local network can access ssh server on that machine.

Comment: I suspect you might be able to do it with tcpwrappers (/etc/hosts.allow) too.

Answer (score 4):

This would be accomplished with `iptables` (netfilter), the built-in firewall utility for Linux.

Depending on what you're doing with your server (and what you're serving), this will need to be (carefully) configured to permit the appropriate traffic.

There's a [good tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) on this at Ubuntu's official help website and there's also [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/firewall.html) (Uncomplicated Firewall) that's built in to Ubuntu to handle the basics.  For example if you wanted to only permit SSH (TCP 22) access from 10.0.0.15, you'd do this:

`sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 10.0.0.15 to any port 22`

You can also use [one](http://www.mista.nu/iptables/) of several handy iptables rule generators to generate an entire iptables ruleset.

Another suggestion (especially if this Ubuntu host will be on the Internet) would be to use [SSH key pairs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) for authentication instead of [passwords](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable_Password_Authentication); I'd also [disable root logins](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/).

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting - to catch the private address range (RFC1918) you probably want 192.168.0.0/16, -not- /8.

Comment: +1. That RFC recommends to limit the network part to not less than 16 bits for the 192.168 based networks. You could even take 192.168.0.0/24 which provides 254 possible addresses. More than enough for most private networks.