# Ubuntu - How limit access to machine ports by ip address

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I have a ubuntu 64 12.04 server on linode and I need to limit access by ip address.  I have never used ip tables and I understand its rather a complex topic. Than than uses sec groups on ec2, I know nothing.

So, I want to keep ssh 22 open but all other ports closed expect 2812 for monit and a couple of UDP ports.

So, what is the easiest methods to accomplish this?

Comment: If you have an Internet connected host, you really do need to invest the time and effort in learning the host platform's firewall and security utilities. IPTables *is* a complex topic, but Internet security is also a complex topic. You'll be glad you made the investment.

Comment: Agreed.  I used uwf and worked great.  Next think I will do is a ssh proxy. Linode does not provide support and the machine is wide open by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish OP answer there are several ways to do allow access to specific ip address [see this](https://serverfault.com/a/403383/105200),

The easiest thing to manage `ufw` in your case is [gufw](http://gufw.tuxfamily.org/) as it allows you edit iptables in Ubuntu without terminal.